# Average POS-TAG Frequency

Tags: python, statistics, nltk, average, pos-tagger

I want to take this tagged text (formatted as such) and find the average frequency of the pos-tag DT in each sentence. ex. DT  appears 1/3 words in sentence1 and 1/3 words in sentence2. Then I want to add these up and divide by the number of sentences in the text (2 in this case). This will give me the average appearance of DT per sentence.

```
 from collections import Counter
 import nltk

 tagged_text = [('A', 'DT'), ('hairy', 'NNS'), ('dog', 'NN')]
 [('The', 'DT'), ('mischevious', 'NNS'), ('elephant', 'NN')]

 for eachSentence in tagged_text:
     Counter(tag for word,tag in tagged)/len(eachsentence.split())

 total = sum(counts.values())

 float(average) = sum(counts.values())/len(tagged_text.sents())
 print(float(average))
```

The big problem for me is the eachSentence part which I don't not how to get around (I don't know how to define what it is). I want this code to be able to be applied to hundreds of sentences that have the same format. I know there are a lot of problems with the code so if someone can please correct them I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want to know how you can assign your hundreds of sentences to the variable `eachSentence`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm (also) not really sure what you are after. Perhaps you should try to structure your idea/requirements a bit more (in your head/on paper) before trying to put it into code. 
Based on your description and code, I can think of two possible figures that you're after, which can be obtained in the following way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tagged_text = [[('A', 'DT'), ('hairy', 'NNS'), ('dog', 'NN')], [('The', 'DT'), ('mischevious', 'NNS'), ('elephant', 'NN')]]

d = defaultdict(int)
t = 0
for sentence in tagged_text:
    for tupl in sentence:
        tag = tupl[1]
        d[tag] += 1
        t += 1

for tag in d:
    print("Likelihood that %s appears in a sentence: %s" % (tag, str(float(d[tag] / len(tagged_text)))))
    print("Likelihood of %s appearing in complete corpus: %s" % (tag, str(float(d[tag] / t))))
```

Resulting in

```
Likelihood that NN appears in a sentence: 1.0
Likelihood of NN in complete corpus: 0.3333333333333333
Likelihood that NNS appears in a sentence: 1.0
Likelihood of NNS in complete corpus: 0.3333333333333333
Likelihood that DT appears in a sentence: 1.0
Likelihood of DT in complete corpus: 0.3333333333333333
```

All three tags appear in both sentences, hence likelihood of it appearing in a sentence is 1. All three tags both appear twice (on a total of six), hence a likelihood of 1/3 for them to appear (not regarding sentence distribution).
But then again, not sure if this is what you're after.

Comment: I tried your code on a file. The content of my file looks like this: [[('In', 'IN'), ('helping', 'VBG'), ('the', 'DT'), ('players', 'NNS'), ('after', 'IN'), ('discarding', 'VBG'), (',', ','), ('always', 'RB')]]. Now is the problem that at the line `tag = tupl[1]` I get an index error, the index 1 is out of range. I don't understand why.